# Register page couldn't register user

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have setup register page by Django. The URL of register input on IE, register page is ok, but I cliked 'register' button on page, no register form display.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnusr.png)

users\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# register page
re_path('^register/$', views.register, name='register'),    
]
```

users\views.py

```
def register(request):
    """register new user"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # display blank register form
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        # deal filled form
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # auto login, and redirect to home page
            authenticated_user =authenticate(username=new_user.username,password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

register.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_P }}

    <button name="submit">register</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" />
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are three methods to render the form.

- {{ form.as_table }} will render them as table cells wrapped in  tags
- {{ form.as_p }} will render them wrapped in

  tags
- {{ form.as_ul }} will render them wrapped in li

You can manually render the form with HTML also but fields name should be the same as the registration form.